# Different encoding results for same UTF-8 character for ã

Tags: encoding, utf-8

One encoding scheme gives `ã as a%CC%83`  and the other gives `ã as %C3%a3`.

What is the difference between these 2? I was debugging this, and found that, `a%CC%83` is actually 2 character. One for `~` which is `%CC%83` and one for `a`. But, how can someone obtain that encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal behavior. In Unicode same symbol can be encoded as single character or as composition of two or more characters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character

Comment: But, the composition one is not working for us. How to disable that. I want encoding as `single character` only

Comment: @VivekVardhan, what programming language are you using? You need to do Unicode Normalization to have precomposed characters, but please note that not all decomposed characters have their precomposed equivalents.

Comment: We are getting request from Android app, which is encoding in this way. And query to Lucene is not giving result with composition encoding, but giving proper results for normal encoding(single character encoding), but for the same ios is sending single character encoded value